# NPE in channel.write(Object message)

Tags: netty

I am running a (selfmade) middleware "Service Connector (SC)" basing on netty (3.2.5.Final.jar) which basically is a proxy for http traffic. Any incoming request is forwarded to a remote node, an apache at the end.

```
public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent event) throws Exception {
        ChannelBuffer msg = (ChannelBuffer) event.getMessage();
        outboundChannel.write(msg);
}
```

I am sending a request over the browser to the SC for example: "http://localhost:9104/testHtml.htm"

it usually works perfect! Occasionally the browser loops forever. Different patterns (different files, sizes, times)

Looking into the netty log:

```
2012-11-28 17:54:12.326+0100 [New I/O server boss #9 ([id: 0x015bdc50, /10.43.18.160:9104])] DEBUG (org.jboss.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler:39) - [id: 0x00f6fd54, /10.43.18.160:52499 => /10.43.18.160:9104] OPEN
2012-11-28 17:54:12.342+0100 [New I/O server boss #9 ([id: 0x015bdc50, /10.43.18.160:9104])] DEBUG (org.jboss.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler:39) - [id: 0x00f6fd54, /10.43.18.160:52499 => /10.43.18.160:9104] BOUND: /10.43.18.160:9104
2012-11-28 17:54:12.357+0100 [New I/O server boss #9 ([id: 0x015bdc50, /10.43.18.160:9104])] DEBUG (org.jboss.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler:39) - [id: 0x00f6fd54, /10.43.18.160:52499 => /10.43.18.160:9104] CONNECTED: /10.43.18.160:52499
2012-11-28 17:54:12.342+0100 [SC_WORKER thread-13] DEBUG (org.jboss.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler:39) - [id: 0x00f6fd54, /10.43.18.160:52499 => /10.43.18.160:9104] CHANGE_INTEREST: 0
2012-11-28 17:54:12.420+0100 [New I/O server worker #9-20] DEBUG (org.jboss.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler:39) - [id: 0x00f6fd54, /10.43.18.160:52499 => /10.43.18.160:9104] RECEIVED: BigEndianHeapChannelBuffer(ridx=0, widx=501, cap=501) - (HEXDUMP: ....)
2012-11-28 17:54:12.435+0100 [SC_WORKER thread-13] DEBUG (org.jboss.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler:39) - [id: 0x00f6fd54, /10.43.18.160:52499 => /10.43.18.160:9104] INTEREST_CHANGED
2012-11-28 17:54:12.451+0100 [SC_WORKER thread-11] DEBUG (org.jboss.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler:43) - [id: 0x00f6fd54, /10.43.18.160:52499 => /10.43.18.160:9104] EXCEPTION: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.serviceconnector.net.res.netty.tcp.proxy.NettyTcpProxyResponderRequestHandler.messageReceived(NettyTcpProxyResponderRequestHandler.java:127)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.execution.ChannelEventRunnable.run(ChannelEventRunnable.java:69)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

In debug mode i can see either msg nor outboundChannel is null :/
if i change to code to the following it works.

just write the message again in case of error

```
try{
  outboundChannel.write(msg);
} catch(Throwable t) {
  outboundChannel.write(msg);
}
```

or slow down the thread

```
Thread.sleep(200);
outboundChannel.write(msg);
```

guess i am facing a race condition. it only happens on slow machines
of course its hard to reproduce, unfor. i am not able to provide an example.

i tried netty 3.5.10.Final with the same behavior. any one observing similar behaviour?
thx!

Comment: Please show me your complete handler..

Comment: sure: http://www.stabilit.ch/download/sc/NettyTcpProxyResponderRequestHandler.java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`outboundChannel` can only be `null` if `messageReceived` is invoked before `channelOpen`.  Usually, it never happens, but it can happen if your pipeline has an `ExecutionHandler` before your handler and you are using an unordered executor service.  If so, please use an `ExecutorService` such as `OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor`.

Comment: thx a lot and sorry, obviously i did not read the ExecutionHandler API carefully enough :/!